# How to print out all of my data from the second table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a CRUD with two tables.

I have completed the CRUD up to the point of the update function.

The problem is that i can't get the data from my second table to print out correctly.

I have tried with for loops, foreach loops, while loops and all the loops I can imagine to try to loop trough the data but nothing seems to work.

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM personal where id=$id") or die($mysqli->error);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $first_name = $row['first_name'];
      $last_name = $row['last_name'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];

      $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM phone where user_id=$id") or die($mysqli->error);

    } while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

      $phone_number2 = $row2['phone_number2'];
      var_dump($phone_number2);
    }
  }
```

The var_dump in the situation dumps all of the data in the table but when i get the same data in the edit page i get only the last result.

THE EDIT PAGE

```
<form class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8" id="userform" name="form" action="process.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg">Name *</label>
          <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" placeholder="Enter your name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg">Last name *</label>
          <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" placeholder="Enter your last name" >
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg">Email *</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Enter your email" >
      </div>

      <div id="tel_number" class="form-group">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
              <label>Phone numbers *</label>
              <input type="tel" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" class="form-control col-md-12" value="<?php echo $phone_number; ?>" placeholder="Enter your phone number" >
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
              <?php if ($phone_number2 > 1): ?>
                <?php var_dump($phone_number2); ?>
                  <input type="tel" id="phone_number2" name="phone_number2" class="form-control col-md-12" value="<?php echo $phone_number2; ?>" placeholder="Enter your phone number" >
              <?php endif ?>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="update_id" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary col-lg" name="update">Update</button>
      </form>
```

The result I'm aiming for is the data from my second table to be printed out in full, regardless if one user have one or seven phone numbers.

The result I'm getting is provided in the link bellow:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gt69ovv16r5lfh7/var_dump%28%24phone_number2%29.png?dl=0

Comment: The second query will only be executed once using the last record. You would have to nest the second while loop inside the first to print all the records, or better yet, use a single query with a join statement.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is in order because the $result2 variable that is processed in the second loop happens to be that of the last user in the first loop whose user_id was queried.
In order to get the phone numbers displayed for each user, the second loop should be nested in the first loop right after the $result2 variable is set.

Comment: Still getting the same result, i have found a way with nesting foreach loop in the edit page, it works but i get an Notice: Undefined variable: phone_number2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\edit.php on line 50 when i don't have data in the second table matching the id from the first table

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!
Solution: 
The code that checks for the edit button

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM personal where id=$id") or die($mysqli->error);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $first_name = $row['first_name'];
      $last_name = $row['last_name'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];

      $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT phone.phone_number2 FROM phone where user_id=$id") or die($mysqli->error);

    } while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

      $phone_number2 = $row2['phone_number2'];
    }
  }
```

The code that prints all of the data from the second table

```
<tr>
              <?php if ($phone_number >= 1): ?>
                <?php foreach ($result2 as $key => $value): ?>
                  <?php foreach ($value as $phone2 => $phone): ?>
                  <input type="tel" id="phone_number2" name="phone_number2" class="form-control col-md-12" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" placeholder="Enter your phone number" >
                  <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
              <?php endif ?>
          </tr>
```